# how can revolve this object?

Tags: motor

This object is for revolving glass stationary for art works. Like the mirror revolving left and right 90' degrees periodically with motor and arduino. 
But today I heard that this servo motor can't bear the 2kg glass(140cm/55inch(width)*20cm/7.87inch(length))
In this situation,How can I revolve the glass?ㅠ.ㅠ

I have a Idea. can you evaluate these?
1) first, attach the large clip(?) in this image to the circle board
and turn the circle board.

I need your H.E.L.P.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mount the rotating element onto a sturdy vertical shaft that is in turn mounted into a pair of ball bearings. Obviously the ball bearing's outside races are secured to the base part of this contraption. Make sure that the whole thing is a nicely balanced load and that it rotates freely.

For moving the thing back and forth you may be able to use your R/C servo with a crank arm and a linkage to the rotating part. The ability of the servo to swing the rotating mass will now become one of how fast it needs to move and the moment of inertia of the rotating load.